# Using ``exec()`` in a comprehension list

Tags: python

I have a script that can be run independently but sometimes will be externally invoked with parameters meant to override the ones defined in the script. I got it working using `exec()` (the safety of this approach is not the point here) but I don't understand why it works in a for loop and not in a comprehension list.

```
foo = 1
bar = 2

externally_given = ['foo=10', 'bar=20']
for ext in externally_given:
    exec(ext)

print('Exec in for loop ->', foo, bar)

externally_given = ['foo=30', 'bar=40']
[exec(ext) for ext in externally_given]

print('Exec in comprehension list ->', foo, bar)
```

Output:

```
Exec in for loop -> 10 20
Exec in comprehension list -> 10 20
```

EDIT: Python version 3.10

Comment: It is because list comprehensions create their own scope

Comment: You bound 30 to foo, and 40 to bar. And then you discarded foo & bar, when the list comprehension when out of scope.

Comment: You shouldn't be using list comprehensions for side effects to begin with

Comment: Oh, I see... so then I was curious and I have tried ```[(exec(ext), print(foo, bar)) for ext in externally_given]``` and it always prints (10, 20), which then seems that even during the (within the scope of) comprehension list, the visible foo and bar are the outer ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To update global variables, let `exec()` have access to them by passing `globals()` as the second parameter:

```
[exec(ext,globals()) for ext in externally_given]
# [None, None]
foo
# 10
bar
# 20
```

(Subject to all the good comments to the original post.)

Comment: Still a terrible idea IMO, this is a concentrate of python anti-patterns. We could call it a "*list incomprehension*" ;)

Comment: I agree is not the best idea and probably there's a hundred ways to do it better. But, is it TERRIBLE?